# Can't extend PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase

Tags: php, tdd, persistence, phpunit, dbunit

I had become totally convinced about TDD and trying to use it by the book, looking forward to have a near to 100% test coverage and always writing tests before new coding.

I'm using phpUnit over ZF and although I can feel some progress somedays, in others I feel like I'm totally stuck.

My application is very database centric and I am in need to begin to test (and code...) database persistence.

I was taking a look at slides from [Testing Lamp Appplications Presentation by Stephenn Bergmann](http://en.oreilly.com/mysql2011/public/schedule/detail/16813) and it seems very clear and straightforward how to test database interaction.

But, always I try to use a class that extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase I have error messages about not finding some class at 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database' namespace.

Probably I´m missing some crucial point, as I have the same problem when I try to follow any of others solutions and suggestions I can find, like an answer and a presentation that I can't link here because of my reputation...

In all cases, when I extends Database_TestCase, some class is not found.

I suspect that there is something related with the way I'm bootstraping, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. The tests I wrote that extend ControllerTestCase work well.

I'm running over Xampp. phpUnit version os 3.6.10, php is 5.3.8, Zend Framework is 1.11.11

I'm using the following phpunit.xml as php configuration:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
<testsuite name="Some">
    <directory>./</directory>
</testsuite>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../library/MyApp/</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
            <file>../application/modules/default/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" hightlight="true" lowupperbound="50" highlowerbound="80">
    <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html">
</log></log></logging>
```

My Bootstrap.php is:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'ControllerTestCase.php';
```

and ControllerTestCase.php

```
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';
class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Zend_Application
    */
    protected $application;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap() {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        $this->application->bootstrap();
    }
}
```

And when I create a Test as, for exemple, this tryTest.php

```
    require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php';

class TryTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {
    /*** any test or even just getConnection ***/
}
```

I receive the following error message or something close to it in other ways I try:

> > Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DefaultTester' not found in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\TestCase.php on
> >     line 132
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0003     326968   1. {main}() C:\xampp\php\phpunit:0
>       0.0141     745152   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46
>       0.0141     745568   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:130
>       0.4012    5280032   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:192
>       0.7182    5750296   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:325
>       2.4058   11441872   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:705
>       2.4060   11442104   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
>       2.4060   11442104   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:772
>       2.4061   11442104   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:751
>       2.4066   11441136  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:649
>       2.4079   11494800  11. PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase->setUp()
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:801
>       2.4080   11494832  12. PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase->getDatabaseTester()
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\TestCase.php:202
>       2.4080   11494832  13. PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase->newDatabaseTester()
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\TestCase.php:92

There is a DefaultTester.php at C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database and I can't figure out what is going on...

I got to this configuration after following this [Zendcast from Jon Lebensold][2]. At that moment, I had some hard times trying to solve some problems, but after some help from @edorian I found that the main problem was between my chair and keyboard... :-/ Probably same situation now...

I even tryed to create a MapperTestCase in a similar way as Jon built his ControllerTestCase.php file, but this didn't help me anyhow.

So, now I'm here, trying to get some help to find what is wrong with my environment or approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if it has solved all problems, but searching at Stackoverflow, I´d find this [question that reported something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099179/phpunit-skeleton-generator-cannot-find-extends-class) to mine:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/AutoLoader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_AutoLoader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('PHPUnit_');
```

When I tried to put the code above at my bootstrap.php, I could at least make         `$connection = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection($pdo, 'mydb');` works

I still can't understand why PHPUnit extensions weren't being find, but, at least I will can advance...